# Paperclip image resizing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip for image uploading in my project. I have overridden the default path already 
( `path: ':class/:id/:attachment/:basename.:extension'`). In that I have missed the style at path name, now I need to add thumbnail for image.Now I have changed the path(

```
    config.paperclip_defaults = {
       styles: { thumb: "40x40" },
       path: ':class/:id/:attachment/:style/:basename.:extension',
       url: ':class/:id/:attachment/:style/:basename.:extension'}
```

) with style and I have uploaded image at S3.
 When I run paperclip rake tasks for previously uploaded files it shows me the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass.
```

when I try reprocess method through console,

```
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
[paperclip] copying users/100000/profile_picture/Screen_Shot_2018-03-13_at_3.46.34_PM.png to local file /var/folders/f_/rp805gln2p7_1z0prxsw7www00015k/T/2bfc1b167915d853fafaa0a3ef5d83d220180319-5563-1cqfhvv.png
NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=User` for creating versions for already created images. You can check more option [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation).

But your current changes to model won't let you do so, Because you changed path from `path: ':class/:id/:attachment/:basename.:extension'` to `path: ':class/:id/:attachment/:style/:basename.:extension'`.

Your already created images are at path something like `abc/123/attachement_name/basename.:extension`. But after your changes paperclip looking it in `abc/123/attachement_name/origional/basename.:extension`.

You can use rake task from [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Changing-attachment-:path). After making minimum changes it will resolve your issue.

```
namespace :paperclip do
  desc "Recreate attachments and save them to new destination"

  task :move_attachments => :environment do

    Model.find_each do |model|
      unless model.image_file_name.blank?
        filename = Rails.root.join('public', 'system', 'images', model.id.to_s, model.image_file_name)

        if File.exists? filename
          #image = File.new filename
          model.remote_image_url = filename
          model.save
          model.image.reprocess! 
          image.close
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Replace `Model` with your model name and images with attachment name and everything will work.

Comment: How to do this with uploaded files at S3

Comment: Instead of rails root, you need to provide initial path for s3 url and then append path with filename. Let me know if still not clear

Comment: Can you explain in detail please

Comment: `filename = Rails.root.join('public', 'system', 'images', model.id.to_s, model.image_file_name)` This line we are creating url using previous configuration. Just do `Object.url` it will return new url remove `/origional` from new url. it will point to actual object. Save image via url.

Comment: In that case the won't the filename change ?

Comment: You find a url in file name. this url need to save in your new configuration. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL this link will help you to save file from url.